# Is using LIMIT in SQLite gives the data or rows in "FIRST IN FIRST OUT" basis?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am using SQLite in my Ionic project, I am saving my Log Files in SQLite server, for this I want to limit the `.db` file with only last 2000 data values in FIRST IN FIRST OUT basis, does using

> LIMIT 2000

will give me the last 2000 values stored or the first 2000 values I have stored (which is not my requirement).

Thanks for the help in advance .

Comment: You can add an order by id or date column to get the first or last 2000 entries.

Comment: Use triggers. When a new row is inserted, let the trigger delete the oldest one.

Comment: Using LIMIT without an ORDER BY gives you arbitrary rows (Depends on joins, indexes, groups, partitions, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL queries return *unordered* sets unless the query has an `ORDER BY`.  This is actually an extension of the fact that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is simply no ordering.

So, using `LIMIT` with no `ORDER BY` returns *arbitrary* rows.  It may look like the rows are ordered, but they are not -- at least no by SQL standards.  You need an `ORDER BY`.

One caveat:  I will admit that SQLite is such a simple database that it only allow one thread per query.  As such, it might actually "reliably" return results in a particular order.  However, I have never found documentation that guarantees this behavior and contradicts the SQL standard.  So, relying on the ordering of a result set with no `ORDER BY` is quite risky, even if it seems to work.